# Own vector class for arduino (c++)

Tags: c++, vector, arduino

I added also void Clear()-method.

https://redstoner.com/forums/threads/840-minimal-class-to-replace-std-vector-in-c-for-arduino

https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=45626.0

I'm asking about this Vector class.

```
void push_back(Data const &x) {
  if (d_capacity == d_size) resize();
  d_data[d_size++] = x;
}; // Adds new value. If needed, allocates more space
```

How to add "insert"-method to this Vector class (arduino use C++ but not have a standard vector methods)?

```
Vector<Sensor*> sensors;
```

I have a another class `Sensor` and I use vector like this.

```
push.back(new Sensor (1,1,"Sensor_1",2));
```

Is it possible to add values one by one to this vector class? And how to do it?

---

I like to ask also other question.

How can I call delete/call destructor for this Vector "sensors" so all pointers are deleted? Or sensors vector is deleted? I want to clear the data and then add data to it.

Comment: _insert_ into a `vector` is not a good idea, nor efficient. You should use a `list` if you want to do insertions. That aside, your question is not clear (at least to me), you already have the `push_back` method to add elements one by one or not?

Comment: @Nacho `push_back` (if implemented correctly) is still `O(1)` amortized.

Comment: Please don't link to parts of your question, include the text/code/images directly. The purpose of SO is not just to answer the question for you but for anyone else who comes along later with the same problem.

Comment: Yeah. My bad. But do somebody know answer for this delete question? It has vector delete method but how to use it? I have not used c++ so much. Or how to fix delete operator?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an item to the end of the vector, use the push_back method you've quoted above. If you want to add an item somewhere else in the vector, you'll need to add your own method which re-sizes if necessary, shifts the elements above the insert location up one place and then copies the new element into the correct slot. Something like this (untested):

```
void insert_at(size_t idx, Data const &data) {
    assert(idx < d_size);
    if (d_capacity == d_size) {
        resize();
    }
    for (size_t i = d_size; i > idx; --i) {
        d_data[i] = std::move(d_data[i - 1]);
    }
    d_data[idx] = data;
    ++d_size;
}
```

As Nacho points out, you might be better off with a linked list if you're going to do a lot of these insert operations, especially if the data you're storing is large and/or has a complex move operator.

Comment: You are not using move constructor here (and you should)

Comment: Edited it, although I don't know if the Arduino C++ lib has std::move in it.

Comment: Still bad. You are calling resize() - which means, you will be default-constructing your elements, only to move into them.

Comment: Well, this is what the original code does (it uses malloc/memcpy), not sure I want to rewrite the whole thing...

Comment: I think there are more bugs in original code, like resize is using d_data to memcpy even if it is nullptr, so if you insert_at on empty vector you will get a crash. Even push_back should fail on very first call.

Comment: I might return `int` or `bool` to let user check if the operation succeeded.

Comment: [code]    void Clear() //here
    {
        memset(d_data, 0, d_size);
        d_capacity = 0;
        d_size = 0;
        free(d_data);
    }[/code] I included also this method. Seems it crash if trying [code]     for(int i=0;i<sensors.size();i++){ delete sensors[i]; } sensors.Clear();[/code] and then push_back();. It not move pointers or something else is wrong?